# Pothos leaves turning white-yellow-brown from the centre

Tags: leaves

This was a Pothos from Ikea, it's doubled in size and was doing well.

Then 2 leaves started to show whiteish-yellow-brown patches in the middle.

I don't think it's over watering as the soils is only a bit moist.

Does anyone know what this is?

Thanks
[image: Pothos leaf going yellow from middle]
[image]

Comment: Do you have it in a south window in full sun?

Comment: No, it living on the window sill in a North facing room.  There is some direct sun, but only briefly in the mornings.

Comment: Or maybe its time for the leaf to dry and fall , other leaves seems healthy , i will say ignore it

Answer (score 2):

It's very normal. Pick off the leaves if you want,. Sometimes the leaves turn brown, pick those off too.
 Pothos has a strong root system. Even if you chopped it all the way back it would come right back. Also it's extremely easy to root in water and stick it in a pot.